# Fetch offset 5705 is out of range for partition , resetting offset

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I am getting below info message every time in kafka consumer.

```
2020-07-04 14:54:27.640  INFO 1 --- [istener-0-0-C-1] c.n.o.c.h.p.n.PersistenceKafkaConsumer   : beginning to consume batch messages , Message Count :11
2020-07-04 14:54:27.809  INFO 1 --- [istener-0-0-C-1] c.n.o.c.h.p.n.PersistenceKafkaConsumer   : Execution Time :169
2020-07-04 14:54:27.809  INFO 1 --- [istener-0-0-C-1] essageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer : Committing: {nbi.cm.changes.mo.test23-1=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=5705, leaderEpoch=null, metadata=''}}
2020-07-04 14:54:27.812  INFO 1 --- [istener-0-0-C-1] c.n.o.c.h.p.n.PersistenceKafkaConsumer   : Acknowledgment Success
2020-07-04 14:54:27.813  INFO 1 --- [istener-0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.consumer.internals.Fetcher       : [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=cm-persistence-notification] Fetch offset 5705 is out of range for partition nbi.cm.changes.mo.test23-1, resetting offset
2020-07-04 14:54:27.820  INFO 1 --- [istener-0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.SubscriptionState    : [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=cm-persistence-notification] Resetting offset for partition nbi.cm.changes.mo.test23-1 to offset 666703.
```

**Got OFFSET_OUT_OF_RANGE error in debug log and resetting to some other partition that actually not exist. Same all messages able to receive in consumer console.**
But actually I committed offset before that only , offset are available in kafka , log retention policy is 24hr, so it's not deleted in kafka.

In debug log, I got below messages:

```
beginning to consume batch messages , Message Count :710
2020-07-02 04:58:31.486 DEBUG 1 --- [ce-notification] o.a.kafka.clients.FetchSessionHandler    : [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=cm-persistence-notification] Node 1002 sent an incremental fetch response for session 253529272 with 1 response partition(s)
2020-07-02 04:58:31.486 DEBUG 1 --- [ce-notification] o.a.k.c.consumer.internals.Fetcher       : [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=cm-persistence-notification] Fetch READ_UNCOMMITTED at offset 11372 for partition nbi.cm.changes.mo.test12-1 returned fetch data (error=OFFSET_OUT_OF_RANGE, highWaterMark=-1, lastStableOffset = -1, logStartOffset = -1, preferredReadReplica = absent, abortedTransactions = null, recordsSizeInBytes=0)
```

When all we will get OFFSET_OUT_OF_RANGE.

Listener Class :

```
@KafkaListener( id = "batch-listener-0", topics = "topic1", groupId = "test", containerFactory = KafkaConsumerConfiguration.CONTAINER_FACTORY_NAME )
    public void receive(
        @Payload List<String> messages,
        @Header( KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_MESSAGE_KEY ) List<String> keys,
        @Header( KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_PARTITION_ID ) List<Integer> partitions,
        @Header( KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_TOPIC ) List<String> topics,
        @Header( KafkaHeaders.OFFSET ) List<Long> offsets,
        Acknowledgment ack )
    {
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        handleNotifications( messages ); // will take more than 5s to process all messages

        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        long timeElapsed = endTime - startTime;

        LOGGER.info( "Execution Time :{}", timeElapsed );

        ack.acknowledge();

        
        LOGGER.info( "Acknowledgment Success" );

    }
```

**Do i need to close consumer here , i thought spring-kafka automatically take care those , if no could you please tell how to close in apring-kafka and also how to check if rebalance happened or not , because in DEBUG log not able to see any log related to rebalance.**

Answer (score 2):

I think your consumer may be rebalancing, because you are not calling `consumer.close()` at the end of your process.

This is a guess, but if the **retention policy isn't kicking in** (and the logs are not being deleted), this is the only reason I can tell for that behaviour.

Update:

As you set them as `@KafkaListeners`, you could just call `stop()` on the **KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry**: `kafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.stop()`

Comment: updated my listener code , could you please check those..